# I want to evaluate the OS(operating system) system property to load the environment corresponding configuration file

Tags: linux

I want to evaluate the OS (operating system) system property to load the environment corresponding configuration file. E.g. if OS evaluates to Windows, the `properties-win.xml` will be loaded *or* if OS evaluates to Unix or Linux, the `properties-unix.xml` will be loaded.

The below spel works fine

```
{(systemProperties['os.name'].indexOf('nix') >= 0 or 
  systemProperties['os.name'].indexOf('nux') >= 0 or 
  systemProperties['os.name'].indexOf('aix') > 0 
 ) ? 'linux' 
   : ((systemProperties['os.name'].indexOf('Win') >= 0) 
      ? 'windows' : 'Unknow OS')}
```

But in place of evaluating the `systemProperties['os.name']` each time, I want to have this in a variable and then wants to match the condition. I saw the `#this` variable usage and tried to make the below spel

```
{systemProperties['os.name'].?
 ((#this.indexOf('nix') >= 0 or 
   #this.indexOf('nux') >= 0 or 
    this.indexOf('aix') > 0 
  ) ? 'unix' : (#this.indexOf('win') >= 0) ? 'windows' : 'Unknown')}
```

But somehow, it's giving parsing exception.

Does anyone can suggest anything? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I reformatted your question to be able to read that code. This makes it easy to spot the issue: look at the second code block, first line, what is the dot (`.`) doing there before the `?`? And the brackets are wired. Also one of the `this` does not have a leading `#`. I cannot say more, since I do not know what language that is...

Comment: How is this question different from [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356757/spring-expression-to-evaluate-os)?