# How to make a bean configuration trigger only when two profiles are active

Tags: spring, spring-java-config, spring-profiles

I have a bean that only should get created iff the two profiles "demo" and "local" both are active. What is the best way to achieve this in a java based Spring Configuration.

What I came up with so far is, creating beans like the following:

```
@Profile("demo")
@Bean("isDemoActive")
public Boolean isDemoActive(){ return true;}
```

And get those injected in the bean creating method and do a if condition on those beans.

Is there a nicer/easier way to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: I think you need to use [@Conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356757/spring-expression-to-evaluate-os/23358308#23358308) annotation to define your own matching rules. And in the class implementing `Condition` you have access to the active profiles with `context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()`. There you check which are active and return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, as per my comment above:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;

public class DoubleProfilesCondition implements Condition {
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context,AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        String[] activeProfiles = context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles();

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < activeProfiles.length; i++) {
            String profile = activeProfiles[i];
            if (profile.equals("profile1") || profile.equals("profile2")) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 2)
            return true;
        return false;
   }
}
```

And the class that dictates which beans are created:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Conditional(DoubleProfilesCondition.class)
public class MyConfig {

    public @Bean
    ExampleService service() {
        ExampleService service = new ExampleService();
        service.setMessage("hello, success!");
        return service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about Conditionals!

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-conditional) the relevant reference documentation.

Comment: Didn't actually implement it, but I put the approach in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a `@ProfileAll` annotation which is very like the standard `@Profile` annotation, but annotated Configurations, Methods, ... are only processed by spring if ***ALL*** of the given profiles are currently active:

ProfileAll.java (Annotation)

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Documented
@Conditional(ProfileAllCondition.class)
public @interface ProfileAll {

    /** The set of profiles for which the annotated component should be registered. */
    String[] value();

}
```

ProfileAllCondition.java (Condition)

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

class ProfileAllCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (context.getEnvironment() != null) {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(ProfileAll.class.getName());
            if (attrs != null) {
                LinkedList<String> profilesActive = new LinkedList<>();
                LinkedList<String> profilesNotActive = new LinkedList<>();
                List<Object> values = attrs.get("value");
                int count = 0;
                for (Object value : values) {
                    for (String profile : ((String[]) value)) {
                        count++;
                        if (context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles(profile)) {
                            profilesActive.add(profile);
                        } else {
                            profilesNotActive.add(profile);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (profilesActive.size() == count) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

use it as follows, e.g.:

```java
@Profile({ "mysql", "cloud", "special" })
@Configuration
public class MySqlConfig {
...
```

MySqlConfig will then only be processed if all three profiles are currently active on startup.